# How to avoid multiple instances of braintree.setup in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal, braintree

I have a simple Braintree payment form in a modal window:

```
$scope.displayModalBraintree = function () {
    $scope.modal = 'modal_payment_form.html', $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
        braintree.setup('tokenStringFromServer', 'paypal', {
            container: 'paypal',
            locale: 'da_dk',
            onReady: function (integration) {
                console.log('ready', integration)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

A button click executes displayModalBraintree, and the very first time everything is fine. A second button click however generates two Paypal buttons, and the log says ready ready.

I have tried to destroy the braintree.setup instance using teardown as explained at https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/29#issuecomment-137555915, though it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

You're setting a new listener for `$includeContentLoaded` every time you call `$scope.displayModalBraintree`. Since those listeners aren't getting cleaned up, you create a new one every time. So the second time you run `$scope.displayModalBraintree`, it calls `braintree.setup` twice. The third time you run it, since there are three listeners now, it runs it three times.

One solution would be to set the listener outside of `$scope.displayModalBraintree`, like this:

```
var clientToken, braintreeVault;

$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
  braintree.setup(clientToken, 'paypal', {
    container: 'paypal',
    onReady: function (integration) {
        braintreeVault = integration;
    }
  })
});

$scope.displayModalBraintree = function () {
  $scope.getToken().then(function (token) {
    clientToken = token;
    $scope.modal = 'modal_payment_form?' + (new Date().getTime());
  })
};
```

Another option would be to destroy the listener after the modal is loaded, but I think it makes more sense to extract it out of the `$scope.displayModalBraintree` function.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I work for Braintree.</sub>

We've updated the documentation surrounding teardown since that Github comment was posted. Try setting `integration = null` in your teardown function as demonstrated in the [code snippet here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript/guides/client-sdk#teardown). If that doesn't work, I'd recommend posting the code where `teardown` is called to help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: Thanks, `integration = null` doesn't help, I have posted a non-working example at https://jsfiddle.net/7h242u3q/1/

First time displaying the modal window, the log outputs:
`ready Object { teardown=function()}
teardown Object { teardown=function()}
nulled null`

Second time displaying the modal window, the log outputs:
`ready Object { teardown=function()}
ready Object { teardown=function()}
teardown Object { teardown=function()}
nulled null`

Comment: I need a workflow for a merchant to add multiple payment details..however when I call the client_token for a client by giving the merchant_id, all I get is the previously added payment methods with no form for entering new details